# How do I structure a sub query for this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that will always have a row for the en-US culture.  I am trying to write a query that will give me results for rows that do not also contain es or fr-CA.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

| TextKey | Culture |
| --- | --- |
| DutyType.SigningCeremonyOnly | en-US |
| DutyType.SigningCeremonyOnly | es |
| DutyType.SubmitOnly | es |
| DutyType.SubmitOnly | en-US |
| DutyType.SubmitOnly | fr-CA |

Comment: Show us what you have already tried.

Comment: use `NOT EXISTS()`

Comment: @Squirrel looks more like a `GROUP BY... HAVING COUNT(CASE...) = 0`

Comment: What results do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking for:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.textkey = t.textkey and t2.culture in ('es', 'fr-CA')
                 );
```

I'm not sure why it is relevant that rows exist for `en-US`.